# Share DB setup data between multiple unit test classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm not sure if true unit tests should strictly interact with external systems like databases, but mine do - the idea being my setup code ensures the DB is in a certain state, then my unit tests expect certain results from methods that get called; I need to check the DB-access code is doing the right thing.

I want to use the same DB test data in multiple test classes and not copy-paste it into each class' `[TestInitialize]` and I'm wondering how best to do this. Options seem to include:

1. Throw it all in an external .sql script and run this
2. Some sort of helper class with a static method

I would prefer the code to update the DB is part of my C# code but wondered if there is a more typical way MSTest projects might handle this?

Comment: referencing external systems is a bad idea. I prefer to create a layer between your data access layer and your business layer. For example have an interface with data access methods and properties. and this can be tested.

Comment: I guess I generally agree but that's how this is set up. Call it a different type of test if that makes you happier :) Integration?

Comment: Does the Db need to be reset for each test or is it used as is an all tests.

Comment: You would use inheritance. You could create a base test class and have the other classes inherit it (including the `[TestInitialize]`). Take a look at this article [Structuring Unit Tests](http://zendeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/01/structuring-unit-tests.html)

Comment: It's the same data - it will not be altered by the code being run in the tests - but we need to ensure it's loaded for each test. I'd not thought of inheriting unit test classes, that could be a good answer.

Comment: @Mr.Boy check my answer based on the article I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use inheritance to share setup data between multiple unit test classes.

You could create a base test class and have the other classes inherit it (including the `[TestInitialize]` which will be called for each test).

Take a look at this article, [Structuring Unit Tests](http://zendeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/01/structuring-unit-tests.html), that shows how to use a test structure for tests that have common setup code for all tests

Using the above link for reference a test structure could look like...

```
[TestClass]
public partial class DbTests {
    protected DbContext db;    

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void Init() { 
        //Virtual so it could be overridden in derived classes if needed.
        //...check the DB-access code is doing the right thing. 
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Test1 : DbTests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_Do_Some_Test(){...}

        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_Do_Some_Db_Test(){...}
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Test2 : DbTests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_Do_Some_Other_Test(){...}
    }    
}
```

I use the above format to structure my tests that share common setup code.